# Distribution of a random variable that is produced by another uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Assume a simple two-step lottery: the reward (denoted by $Y$) is a random variable and realized as follows:

First: random variable $X$ is drawn from uniform distribution by interval $(a,c)$.

Second: After the realization of $X$, a player determines reward ($Y$) stochastically:

- with probability $\alpha$: reward is $bX$  ($b$ is constant)
- with probability $1-\alpha$: reward is $X$

Now, what is the distribution of the random reward $Y$?

If the solution is weighted average on both states: i.e. $Y=\alpha bX+(1-\alpha)X=(\alpha b+1-\alpha )X$

then we can say $Y$ is a linear rescaling transformation of $X$ and so $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ has. But I am suspicious that $Y$ really is a weighted average of $X$ and $bX$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201/75923), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/75923) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @drhab the post is edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the event that the reward is taken to be $bX$.

Then:$$P(Y\leq y)=P(E)P(Y\leq y\mid E)+P(E^c)P(Y\leq y\mid E^c)=$$$$\alpha P(bX\leq y\mid E)+(1-\alpha)P(X\leq y\mid E)$$
If moreover $1_E$ and $X$ are independent then this reduces to:$$P(Y\leq y)=\alpha P(bX\leq y)+(1-\alpha)P(X\leq y)\tag1$$

Can you take it from here?

---

Looking at it as weighted average as in your question the stochastic character of the choice is disregarded.

Actually we are dealing with:$$Y=1_EbX+(1-1_E)X\tag2$$where $1_E$ is a random variable (Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\alpha$).

This instead of $\alpha bX+(1-\alpha)X$.

Comment: I don t know the {1} operator. What does it mean in probability theory?

Comment: @dirhab Thanks. Can we say since the interval of $X$ is $(a,c)$, if $b>0$ so the interval of Y is $(\min(ba,a), \max(bc,c))$ ? and since $X \sim unif(a,c)$ so $Y \sim unif(\min(ba,a), \max(bc,c))$?

Comment: If $F$ denotes the CDF of $X$ and $G$ denotes the CDF of $Y$ and $b>0$ then according to my answer:$$G(y)=\alpha F(y/b)+(1-\alpha)F(y)$$You can find an expression of the PDF of $Y$ by taking the derivative of CDF $G$.

Comment: @dirhab thanks again. Does $P(Y≤y)=\alpha P(bX≤y)+(1−\alpha)P(X≤y)$ result in $Y=1_E bX+(1−1_E)X$ or vice versa? and please introduce me {1} operator in probability theory if it's possible. tnx

Comment: If $E$ denotes some event then $1_E$ is a notation for the random variable that takes value $1$ if $E$ occurs and takes value $0$ otherwise. Further statement $(2)$ in my answer stands on itself and is not so much a consequence of statement $(1)$. It is more the other way around. What I actually did was replacing probability $\alpha$ by a random variable that takes value $1$ with probability $\alpha$ on takes value $0$ otherwise. Statement $(2)$ is the result of that and $1_E$ denotes this random variable. Based on $(2)$ we can find $(1)$ so things are a bit upside down.

Answer (score 3):

The statement "$Y$ is a weighted average of $X$ and $bX$" is false.

What is true is: "the density (or CDF) of $Y$ is a weighted average of the densities (or CDF) of $X$ and $bX$".

This is known as a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).

Comment: thanks. If X~unif(a,c) what's the distribution of bX (and its interval)?

Comment: @muhamad Assuming $b$ is positive: it should be obvious that $bX$ is $ unif(ab,cb)$

Comment: Thanks. And what about $Y$? If $b>0$, is $Y \sim unif(\min(ba,a),\max(bc,c))$? @leonbloy